# What's the purpose of auto added QLayout with objectName '_layout'

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5, qlayout

I was exploring Qt layouts and widget management and have come across the behaviour I can't explain.

I have a base UI with the following hierarchy:

```
MainWindow(QMainWindow) ->
    centralwidget (QWidget),
    menubar(QMenuBar),
    statusbar(QStatusBar)
```

Later I add several layouts and widgets to the centralwidget, but, I beleive, it's not important in this context.

Now, if we check MainWindow's children objects and their objectNames we will see the following:

```
<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QLayout object at 0x00000000089425E8> _layout
<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QWidget object at 0x00000000087C6F78> centralwidget
<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QMenuBar object at 0x0000000008942048> menubar
<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QStatusBar object at 0x00000000089420D8> statusbar
```

For some reason, a QLayout object `_layout` appears. But this is not all. It seems to me that this QLayout is not persistent and, occasionally, is being added and removed, for example on resize. I have added an eventFilter for a resize event, and here are the object addresses after several window resizes:

```
<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QLayout object at 0x0000000008942708> _layout
<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QLayout object at 0x00000000089425E8> _layout
<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QLayout object at 0x0000000008942798> _layout
<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QLayout object at 0x00000000089428B8> _layout
```

The layout is there, but every time the object is new.

What's going on here? What's the purpose of this QLayout, and why it behaves this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `QMainWindow` class has a built-in custom layout that manages all the toolbars, menubars, dock-widgets, statusbar and central-widget area:

[image: main-window-layout]

This layout cannot be removed, or replaced by a different layout. If you try to do that, Qt will complain (or possibly even crash).

The object id shown in the `repr` doesn't mean much. This is the id of the PyQt wrapper for the layout and not the memory address of the underlying C++ object. The layout is actually a `QMainWindowLayout` - but that is not a public type, so PyQt can only return a `QLayout` (which is its base-class). It is likely that PyQt is returning a new wrapper around the same underlying C++ object every time you access it.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! And you are right, for some reason PyQt returns a new wrapper around the same underlying C++ object. I searched for a way to get the address of a wrapped object and found ```sip.unwrapinstance(obj)```. It returns the same address for these different Python wrappers.